# What are the various files that could have PATH declarations for OS X Terminal in them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, system-administration

So I'm having a path issue on OS X Leopard. It seems OS X is adding other paths that I'm not stating and it's messing with my path priority. I only have a `.bash_login` file, I don't have a `.bashrc` or a .profile file. My `.bash_login` file is as such:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

When I run export this is the path it returns:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
```

Any ideas on what could be putting /usr/bin in there and how I could get `/usr/local/bin` to be a higher priority.

I'm tagging this for Rails too because that's what I'm working on right now... it seems the Mac built-in Ruby, Rails, and Gems are taking priority over the one I have installed at `/usr/local/bin`, figured maybe you fellow Rubyists could help too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you looked inside these two directories:

```
/etc/paths.d/
/etc/manpaths.d
```

Any paths defined in files in those directories get appended automatically to PATH variable -- I mostly use those two directories to put third-party installed applications in the PATH. Also, do have a look at the man page of `path_helper` on OS X.

**EDIT**: Looking at the contents of `/etc/profile`, I can see that `path_helper` is executed first. The man page for `path_helper` says that prior to reading files in `/etc/paths.d/` and `/etc/manpaths.d/` directories, `path_helper` reads and sets up the paths defined in the files `/etc/paths` and `/etc/manpaths`. A look at `/etc/paths` reveals this:

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

And, I believe, those account for the half of what you are seeing as set in PATH.

Comment: Thanks ayaz, that at least told me how X11 and git paths were getting added on there. Still on the hunt for the other items.

Comment: @Tim K: The edit of my reply what I am to believe accounts for the other items.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your changes aren't being applied. Note no /usr/local/mysql/bin

Read the bash manpage section on INVOCATION, .bash_login is only read if it is a login shell -- which the terminal shell is not. You need to put it into ~/.bashrc instead. It will be read for logins and non-login shells.

Comment: +1 don't have it working quite yet - but the man page gives me a start Brian thanks. I'm wondering if a complete logoff is necessary for the bashrc to load?

Comment: have you tried "source .bashrc" as this command will exe that file

Answer (score 1):

You can also put stuff into ~/.MacOSX/Environment.plist, as detailed at https://web.archive.org/web/20150330034300/http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/AquaEnvVar.html

This will make the Environment Variables available to all applications, not just those started through a terminal (bash) session.

(It seems that there is a better suggestion there now, too)

Answer (score 0):

I've also come across an interesting article on Apple's support forums:

[.bash_login no longer executed](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7976259&tstart=0)

With that information I found an overlooked blank .bash_profile file that I had that was loading - and killing all of the information I was trying to set in my path.

So I guess it looks like we could have several "correct" answers depending on the situation.

Comment: What I do is to toss all user-specific BASH initialisation stuff in ~/.bashrc, and place a line in ~/.bash_profile to source ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Just put in .bashrc or .login and you'll be fine