# changing $PATH by editing .bash_profile

Tags: mysql, bash, unix, terminal, zsh

I am having some trouble changing my $PATH variable to include my recent mysql install. This is what I did. In a terminal session (using the zsh shell) I typed

```
nano .bash_profile
```

Inside of this file I put

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

I exit, save, and when I type

```
cat .bash_profile
```

I can see the file was edited properly but when I close the terminal session, open a new window, and type

```
echo $PATH
```

I get the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

So not only is my new mysql path not in there but it didn't change at all. It must be saved in a different file besides .bash_profile correct? Any ideas which one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you source it? (source .bash_profile)

Comment: Are you expecting a zsh shell to source bash init files?

Comment: Put an `echo "in bash profile"` as the first line of `.bash_profile` to see if it's being executed at all.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I was editing the wrong file. Since I am using zsh shell I needed to edit the .zshrc file

Comment: Zsh is discussed here: http://serverfault.com/questions/110065/what-profile-is-my-current-shell-using

Comment: Ahh...totally missed the zsh portion of the question.

Comment: The best place is orobably `.profile` - just make sure Bash and Zsh also read this file. It is the initialization file for the traditional Bourne shell. It is customarily `source`d from `.bash_profile` (dunno about zsh).

Comment: A general question to S.O. gurus. is it possible for Guillermo to just close/delete this question as it really is only PEBKAC ;-) .... I see this happen a lot, and I keep finding the question weeks later as unanswered. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to add paths to the environment in OS X is to create entries in `/etc/paths.d`, so in this case you might put "/usr/local/mysql/bin" into `/etc/paths.d/mysql`. More info in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347286/what-are-the-various-files-that-could-have-path-declarations-for-os-x-terminal-i).

Answer (score 1):

You can add:
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
into your .bash_profile file and you need to RESTART the terminal 
or open new tab to check the added path.